# Getting top 2 rows in each group without row_number() in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a simple query to get result of 2 rows with latest invoice date in each group. Although this task can be accomplished by a `row_number()` that you can see in below code ,I need an alternative to this with minimum complexity.

Code :

```
create table #tt
(
    id int,
    invoiceDT datetime
)

insert into #tt
values(1,'01-01-2016 00:12'),(1,'01-02-2016 06:16'),(1,'01-01-2016 00:16')
    ,(2,'01-01-2016 01:12'),(2,'04-02-2016 06:16'),(2,'01-06-2016 00:16')

select *
from (
SELECT id,invoiceDT,row_number() over(partition by id order by invoiceDT desc) as rownum
FROM #tt
)tmp
where rownum <=2
```

I need same result that is returned by above query

Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: What is a "minimum of complexity"?  `row_number()` is probably the simplest method.

Comment: And what's wrong for you with `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: Well, how would you get the latest? Then, how would you get the second latest in terms of the latest?

Comment: It would definitely help to know why you cannot use `ROW_NUMBER()` since the same reason(s) may invalidate other possible answers also.

Comment: Gordan , complexity interms of query. Not too big . I was   thinking to get the same result by different way. Although ranking functions are optimized but we should have alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Strange request, but here you go:

```
WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT distinct id FROM #tt t1
)
SELECT x.*
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY
( 
  SELECT top 2 * 
  FROM #tt
  WHERE CTE.id = id
  ORDER BY invoiceDT desc
) x
```